# Python triangle quest, arithmetical operation inside print

Tags: python

I try solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-quest-1)
I know that, I can do that like

```
for i in range(1,input()): 
    print int(str(i)*i)
```

It works, but I can't use strings, so i have idea to do
that like

```
for i in range(1,input()): 
    sum+=10**i
    print i*((1+sum)%10**i)
```

---

```
for i=1   1*(1+10)%10, 

for i=2   2*((1+110)%100), 

for i=3   3*((1+1110)%1000) etc.
```

But it doesn't work and have more than 2 lines :( Anyone have idea how to solve this problem ? Generally i know how to solve this problem mathematic but i don't know how to do that in python ( no use string and write no more than 2 lines)

Comment: Ok i have solution. just -  print i*((11111)%10**i)

Comment: That will only work for n <= 6. You would need to do `print i*((11111111)%10**i)` in order to cover up to n=9. My solution below works just as well though.

Comment: @Rarez care to explain how that works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something that helps here is the equation for a "[Repunit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit)". Taking the equation for the i'th Repunit from that Wikipedia page, and substituting 10 in for b (base 10), we get the equation `(10**i - 1) / (10 - 1)` or `(10**i - 1) / 9`. This results in the sequence: `1, 11, 111, 1111...`. Multiplying by i, we achieve the desired result:

```
>>> for i in range(1, input()):
...    print(i * (10**i - 1) // 9)
5<Enter>
1 
22
333
4444
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing it this way (notice I took floor division here):

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print(i*((10**i)//9))
```

for input 5, it yields:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1): #More than 2 lines will result in 0 score. Do not leave a blank line also
    print(int(((10**i)-1)/9)**2)
```

input: 9
output: 12345678987654321

Answer (score 0):

I do have two logical codes which are more lean towards programming language utility rather than the mathematical but it doesnt work for your "Triangle Quest" @ Hackerrank 
code 1:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())): 
    list(print(i,end="\n"*int(j/i)) for j in range(1,i+1))
```

code 2:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    list(print(i,end="") if i!=j else print(i) for j in range(1,i+1))
```